# jQuery not finding checkBox value in dynamic created table / cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the value of a "CheckBox" ( 0, 1, 2 ) from a dynamically created Table when Button clicked. The checkBox is in last cell of each row of table.  jQuery does not give me the "value" when the checkBox is clicked.  Here is my code:

```
<body>

<table id="DataTable" 
style="position:absolute;left:348px;top:80px;width:350px;height:10px;z-
index:7;text-align:center;"></table>

<input type="submit" id="Button4" name="Clk_In" value="Create Table" 
style="position:absolute;left:495px;top:250px;width:96px;height:35px;z-
index:0;">


<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>  // jQuery code below 

var count = 0;

// create table heading & rows by clicking button
$(document).on("click","#Button4", function() {               

    drawHeading();

    for( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
       drawRow();
    }
});

function drawHeading() {

var row = $("<tr />")
$("#DataTable").append(row);
row.append($("<th>" + "Trans#" + "</th>"));
row.append($("<th>" + "DayOfYear" + "</th>"));
row.append($("<th>" + "Vendor" + "</th>"));
row.append($("<th>" + "Amount&nbsp;($)" + "</th>"));
row.append($("<th>" + "Remove" + "</th>"));

}

function drawRow( ) {

var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#DataTable").append(row);
    row.append($("<td>" + "cell1" + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + 2  + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + "cell3" + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + 4 + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td/>").append($('<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox2" 
     value="' + count + '"/>')));

    count += 1;
    //alert("count: " + count);
 }

// find checkBox value   *** NOT WORKING should show 0 or 1 or 2  *** 
var checkboxValues = [];

$('input[name=chkbox2]:checked').map(function() {
    checkboxValues.push($(this).val());
});

alert(checkboxValues[0]);

</script>
```

Any expert advise would be greatly appreciated.
Greg

Comment: Java? Are you sure that this question is Java related? I've removed the Java question tag as it does appear to be inappropriate.

Comment: Not really sure about the way you are appending the input. At least I'm sure this would work for an input (not sure if this is the issue though): `$('<input/>', { type: 'checkbox', name: 'chkbox2', value: count })`

Comment: You are looking for checked inputs before they are created. Create the HTML, then do your input check.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for the checkbox values even before creating the HTML. You can move your code to click event handler of button.

```
<script>  
// jQuery code below 

    var count = 0;

    // create table heading & rows by clicking button
    $(document).on("click","#Button4", function() {               

        drawHeading();

        for( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
           drawRow();
        }

         // find checkBox value
    var checkboxValues = [];

    $('input[name=chkbox2]:checked').map(function() {
        checkboxValues.push($(this).val());
    });

    alert(checkboxValues[0]);

    });

    function drawHeading() {

    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#DataTable").append(row);
    row.append($("<th>" + "Trans#" + "</th>"));
    row.append($("<th>" + "DayOfYear" + "</th>"));
    row.append($("<th>" + "Vendor" + "</th>"));
    row.append($("<th>" + "Amount&nbsp;($)" + "</th>"));
    row.append($("<th>" + "Remove" + "</th>"));

    }

    function drawRow( ) {

    var row = $("<tr />")
        $("#DataTable").append(row);
        row.append($("<td>" + "cell1" + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + 2  + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + "cell3" + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + 4 + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td/>").append($('<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox2" 
         value="' + count + '"/>')));

        count += 1;
        //alert("count: " + count);
     }

    </script>
```

If you want to get the values on checking the checkbox you can listen to the checkbox change event.

```
$('input[name=chkbox2]').change(function() {
        //perform your logic
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not after is appended. Use "map" function when the object is appending.

`row.append($("<td/>").append($.map(this.items, function (item, index) {
    checkboxValues.push($(this).val());
})));`